# $http.get returns a result only after page refresh in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I have an application built on the MEAN stack, running on localhost. On a REST endpoint called `/metrics` offered by NodeJS, I am reading with `$http.get` the contents in order to display it in a view on frontend.

The first time I load the view in the browser:

```
METRICS Array[0]
```

After a refresh:

```
METRICS [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

And the code:

**parserCtrl.js**

```
/*global angular */
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('angularApp.controllers')
    .controller('parserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http) {        
       $http.get('/metrics')
        .success(function (data) {       
            $scope.metrics = data;     
            console.log("METRICS", $scope.metrics);         
        })   
    }]);
}());
```

And in view:

**parser.html**

```
 <div class="row" ng-if="metrics">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 ng-if="metrics">Additional metrics: </h2>           
        </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="metric in metrics">
        <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="metric.name === 'blank'">Blank node count</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9" ng-if="metric.name === 'blank'">{{metric.value}}</div>

        <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="metric.name === 'literals'">Literals count</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9" ng-if="metric.name === 'literals'">{{metric.value}}</div>
    </div>
```

What could be the problem? Is there any other way to do the call in AngularJS so that to get data from a REST endpoint?

Cheers,
Iulia

Comment: you are doing the `console.log` (to see `$scope.metrics` value) on the success callback so i supose your server is sending an empty data at 1st time. Maybe session error or dunno. I don't think that is a frontend error. Log your `response` data on nodejs to see what is sending the server.

Comment: You are right, the /metrics is empty the first time I access it. NodeJS code: 
`app.get('/metrics', function(req, res) {

    res.json(ont.metrics);  //constructed data of triples, nodes, edges

});` How could I modify it though, such that the `/metrics` REST populates the values correctly ?

Comment: how do you get the `ont.metrics` value? please update your question with some of your nodejs code

Comment: ont.metrics is created in a function initEdges()   `//REST endpoint on /ontology/edges  
app.get('/ontology/edges', function(req, res) {  

    initEdges();  
    res.json(ont.filter);  
});`  After this follows the code from my previous comment.

Comment: nodejs is async. try to use a library like `q` or launch the `res` in a callback of `initEdges`

Comment: I will try the idea with the callback, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Node.js. The `/metrics` were initialized using the function `initEdges()`. `initEdges()` was called in another function called `/parser`

Solution:

```
$http.get('/parser')
                .success(function (data) {                          
                            $scope.parser = data;                                                   
                  console.log("JAVA METRICS", $scope.parser);    
                    $http.get('/metrics').success(function (dataMetrics) {       
                     $scope.metrics = dataMetrics;     
                    console.log("RDFSTORE METRICS", $scope.metrics);         
                    }).error(function(data) {       
                      console.log("Could not get RDFSTORE metrics");
                    });
                  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $timeout

```
$http.get('/metrics')
.success(function (data) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.metrics = data;
    }, 100);
    console.log("METRICS", $scope.metrics);
})
```

or

Maybe it about caching you can see it [Caching $http requests in AngularJS](http://geek.bluemangointeractive.com/caching-http-requests-in-angularjs/)

Comment: I think that the problem might be on the node.js end :( thanks for the suggestion though.